Globally hyperbolic spacetimes and (1+3) decomposition
I am having trouble in understanding the relation between globally hyperbolic manifolds and the (1+3)-decomposition used in general relativity. Let me start with the following two preliminaries:

Let $(M,g)$ be a globally hyperbolic Lorentzian manifold. By a
well-known theorem of Bernal/Sanchez (e.g. arXiv:gr-qc/0401112), it is known that such a
manifold is globally isometric to one of the form
$$M\cong\mathbb{R}\times S, \quad g=-N^{2}dt^2+h_{t}$$ where $N$
is smooth positive function, $S$ a Cauchy hypersurface and
$(h_{t})_{t}$ a family of Riemannian metrics on $S$. The
function $t:M\to\mathbb{R}$ has the property that its gradient is
timelike. Now, since I have a product manifold
$\mathbb{R}\times\Sigma$, I can take arbitrary local coorindates on $S$, which
we denote by $(x^{i})$ on $U\subset S$ open, to obtain a coordinate system on $M$ by
$(x^{0}:=t,x^{i})$ on $\mathbb{R}\times U$. In this coordinates, the metric can be written
as $$g=-N^{2}d t^2+(h_{t})_{ij}dx^{i}dx^{j}$$ It is important to
stress that only the metric $h$ here depends on time but not the
hypersurface $\Sigma$ or its coordinates $x^{i}$.
Now, on the other hand, in the (1+3)-formalism, one takes a
Lorentzian manifold $M$ and a foliation $(S_{t})_{t}$ of
spacelike hypersurfaces and decomposed the metric locally as
$$g=-(N^{2}+X_{i}X^{i})dt^2+2X_{i}dtdx^{i}+h_{ij}dx^{i}dx^{j}$$
where $x^{i}$ are coordinates on $S_{t}$. So, its a bit
different here: Since my hypersurfaces depend on time
$(\Sigma_{t})_{t}$, choosing coordinates on each $S_{t}$, they
might depend on time in the sense that they get shifted under the
infinitesimal shift $t\mapsto t+dt$. This is taken into account by
the shift vector, which is defined by $n=N\partial_{t}+X$, where $n$
denotes the normal vector fields of $S_{t}$.


Question: How are these two things related? Of course, in the globally-hyperbolic manifold case (1), I obtain a foliation via $S_{t}:=\{t\}\times S$, but it seems to me that whenever I take coordinates on $(x^{i})$ on $S$, the metric $g$ will always have a zero shift vector, i.e. $X_{i}=0$.
Of course, (2) might be more general, since we do not necessarily
assume $M$ to be globally hyperbolic. However, in the end, in all the
applications of the (1+3) decomposition such as numerical relativity
or the initial value formalism, one restricts to globally hyperbolic
manifolds. So, isn't the shift vector then completely redundant in
this case?

My guess: I am not sure about this, but maybe the reason is the specific choice of time function in (1)? I mean, $t$ for globally hyperbolic manifolds its chosen such that $dt$ is timelike. In particular, the normal vector of $\Sigma$ is globally (and coordinate-independent) given by $n=\beta^{-1}\partial_{t}$. Hence, it seems that this choice always implies that the shift vector is zero, independently on the coordinates chosen. Of course, if I choose a different foliation, but I keep the time function $t$ fixed, then I will get a non-trivial shift vector, but this is a different story.

In point 1, is that your assumption that the hypersurface $\Sigma$ does not depend on time or is it part of the theorem? In the latter case can you point to the reference? In general I think that the embedding of $S$ into the spacetime could change with time, no it is natural to have crossed terms $dt dx^i$

@Pipe Yes, the theorem says that $(M,g)$ is globally of the form $\mathbb{R}\times\Sigma$ with metric $g=-N^{2}dt^{2}+h_{t}$. The are many references since this theorem is quite famous but I guess, one of the original ones is arXiv:gr-qc/0401112. So, in this case, choosing any coordinate system on $\Sigma$ and completing it with $x^{0}=t$ to coordinates on $M$, I get $g_{00}=-N^{2}$ and $g_{0i}=0$. So it seems to be me, that for globally hyperbolic spacetimes there is no shift, at least when considering it in the form $(\mathbb{R}\times\Sigma,g=-N^{2}dt^{2}+h_{t})$.

Of course, I do understand the origin of the shift in the approach (2): If I take an arbitrary foliation $(\Sigma_{t})_{t}$ of some manifold $M$, not even necessarily globally hyperbolic, then clearly I have to take into account a shift.

In theorem 1.1 the metric $g = -Ndt^2 + h_t$ has the property that $h_t$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R} \times S$ not just $S$ and so you could have $dtdx^i$ terms...

@Pipe Sure, but by definition, the restriction of $h_t$ to $\Sigma_t$ is a Riemannian manifold. So, this cross terms are not there.

@Pipe, I mean take the global metric $g=-\beta^{2}d t^2+h_{t}$ and choose coordinates $(x^{i})$ on $\Sigma$, then you get $g=-\beta^{2}dt^{2}+(h_{t})_{ij}dx^{i}dx^{j}$. I don't see why you should get cross terms there. See also this paper arXiv:2110.13672 [gr-qc] at page 10 on top.
